# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки Enter, JButton срабатывал?

Tags: java

Я просмотрел похожие вопросы. Но так-как не понял обращаюсь в отдельном вопросе. Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вам нужно копать в сторону интерфейса KeyListener. Здесь дан хороший пример, как он работает http://java-lang.at.ua/publ/obrabotka_sobytij/keylistener_obrabotka_sobytij_klaviatury/2-1-0-4

Ну например:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            if(e.getKeyCode() == 10){ //10 - код клавиши Enter
                // какой-то код, который должен выполниться
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

вам надо назначить кнопку по умолчанию, которая как раз и срабатывает при нажатии enter

```
JButton enter = new JButton();
JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(enter); 
rootPane.setDefaultButton(enter);
```